# How to extract a network neighbourhood in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like to count the number of links in an agent's (undirected) network neighbourhood. This is the links among an agent and all of the agents that it is linked with. (So if I have two friends who don't know each other it would output 2 links; if they do know each other it would output 3.) In igraph I would use [make_ego_graph](http://igraph.org/r/doc/ego.html).

Anyone know how to achieve this in NetLogo?

Comment: My general approach would be to construct the agentset of ego + network neighbours, then construct the link agentset by running through the agents and ask them to add any links that are with other members of the agentset, then count the link agentset. Have a go and post the code you get stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

Jen's approach is generally right, and there is a concise way to express it in NetLogo. Try something like this:

```
ask one-of turtles [
  let neighborhood (turtle-set self link-neighbors)
  show link-set [ [ link-with myself ] of neighborhood ] of neighborhood
]
```

If I understood what you needed correctly, I think it should do the trick.